# container hasChildNodes() showing null value. Why

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div  id="history">
      <div id="histheading" class="pull-left">History</div>
      <div id='hist'><canvas id="test"></canvas></div>
</div>


 var left=100;
 var t=-150;
 function doHistory_double()
    {
        var data = localStorage.getItem('HTML5TTT');
        data = JSON.parse(data);
            data.reverse();
        var container = document.getElementById('hist');
        // Clear the container
        while (container.hasChildNodes())
        {

            container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
        }
        // Loop through the data
        canvID = 0;
        for(x in data)
        {
            var i=1;
            var hist = data[x];
            if(hist.datetime == undefined)
                break;
            var elem = document.createElement('div');

            elem.style.marginLeft=lef + "px";
            if(i==1){
            elem.style.marginTop=t + "px";
            }
            else
            elem.style.marginTop="0px";
            i++;
            elem.innerHTML = "<p><strong>"+hist.datetime+"</strong><br>Winner: "+hist.winner+"<br><canvas  id='can"+canvID+"' width='100px' height='100px' ></canvas>";
            container.appendChild(elem);
            drawMiniBoard_double(document.getElementById("can"+canvID),hist.board);
            canvID++;
            lef+=310;

        }


    }
```

This is my javscript code. hist is a div showing history of the game.I am getting error as Cannot call method 'hasChildNodes' of null.I am getting this error after i did something using the variable left and t i.e margin-top and margin-left. Help me to solve this.

Comment: It means that `container` is `null`, i.e. an element with ID `hist` doesn't exist at the moment you are calling the function. Since what you posted is not a complete example, it's difficult to give a concrete solution. Please see [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) for general suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

write it in a function and call it onload of document.

```
function deleteChildren() {
    var container = document.getElementById('hist');
    // Clear the container
    while (container.hasChildNodes())
    {
        container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
    }
}


<body onload="deleteChildren()">
  <div  id="history">
      <div id="histheading" class="pull-left">History</div>
      <div id='hist'><canvas id="test"></canvas></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

its working perfectly.. check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLC3R/)

I have bind the click method then calling the code you provided and alert to show either we got a child inside the container or not..

--HTML--

```
<div  id="history">
      <div id="histheading" class="pull-left">History</div>
      <div id='hist' onclick=f()><canvas id="test"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

-- JS --

```
function f()
{    
        var container = document.getElementById('hist');
    // Clear the container
        alert(container.hasChildNodes());
    while (container.hasChildNodes())
    {
        container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FLC3R/

Comment: Actually the container has child , it is returning true for haschildnodes(). But i am getting error " Cannot call method 'hasChildNodes' " . How to clear the error. ? Thanks

Comment: see u accepted its returning true mean its calling the method then only it will return TRUE/FALSE.. then whats the problem, in which line u are getting error.

Comment: i am getting error on this line- while (container.hasChildNodes())

Comment: well @Jack I am not sure why you are getting error.  As code seems ok.  no issue with that.  Do one thing declare a variable above the `while(***)` and then assign the value in that variable and use alert to check either u r getting the correct value or not? and pass that variable in `while(variable_here)`    As I did in above code.